# How was the Shellshock Bash vulnerability found?

Tags: bash, shellshock, bugs, vulnerability

Since this bug affects so many platforms, we might learn something from the process by which this vulnerability was found: was it an εὕρηκα (eureka) moment or the result of a security check?

Since we know Stéphane found the Shellshock bug, and others may know the process as well, we would be interested in the story of how he came to find the bug.

Comment: Related: his [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157495/1174) to "When was the shellshock (CVE-2014-6271/7169) bug introduced, and what is the patch that fully fixes it?".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a particular person's thought process and not any specific *nix issue.

Comment: @Anthon why does this have to be about Linux? Why approve an edit that brings in someone's opinion as though it were OP's?

Comment: @muru I found this an improvement, luckily it takes more than one person to approve a suggested edit. But I have to admit I missed that the question was already closed, otherwise I might not have left it Linux, Unix, I don't care to much, otherwise we need BSD etc in the title of the site as well.

Comment: Don't assume I read each and every question on this site. See http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.security.oss.general/14177/focus=14312 for a short answer.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas those links (and the links to it) look like they could be made into an answer. If you are willing to answer, this could be reopened. Otherwise there is no point. This question currently has 12 upvotes (and 2 downvotes), so some people at least are interested.

Comment: If it gets reopen and you ping me, I'll try and answer it. However, I'm not sure it has a lot of value _now_. A lot of people wondered about it at the time of the disclosure, but I'd doubt many do now or would in a few months time.

Comment: I think it is (still) of interest. I've requested terdon and slm to reopen in chat.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Reopened, so you can answer if you want. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To reassure a few, I didn't find the bug by observing exploits, I have
no reason to believe it's been exploited before being disclosed
(though of course I can't rule it out). I did not find it by
looking at `bash`'s code either.

I can't say I remember exactly my train of thoughts at the time.

That more or less came from some reflection on some behaviours of
some software I find *dangerous* (the behaviours, not the
software). The kind of behaviour that makes you think: *that
doesn't sound like a good idea*.

In this case, I was reflecting on the common configuration of
ssh that allows passing environment variables unsanitised from
the client provided their name starts with `LC_`. The idea is so
that people can keep using their own language when `ssh`ing into
other machines. A good idea until you start to consider
how complex localisation handling is especially when UTF-8 is
brought into the equation (and seeing how badly it's handled by
many applications).

Back in July 2014, I had already reported a vulnerability in
glibc localisation handling which combined with that `sshd`
config, and [two other *dangerous behaviours* of the `bash` shell](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.security.oss.general/13326/focus=13404)
allowed (authenticated) attackers to hack into git servers
provided they were able to upload files there and `bash` was
used as the login shell of the git unix user (CVE-2014-0475).

I was thinking it was probably a bad idea to use `bash` as the login
shell of users offering services over ssh, given that it's quite
a complex shell (when all you need is just parsing a very simple command line) and has inherited most of the misdesigns of ksh.
Since I had already identified a few problems with `bash` being
used in that context (to interpret ssh `ForceCommand`s), I was
wondering if there were potentially more there.

`AcceptEnv LC_*` allows any variable whose name starts
with `LC_` and I had the vague recollection that `bash` *exported
functions* (a *dangerous* albeit at time useful feature) were
using environment variables whose name was something like
`myfunction()` and was wondering if there was not something
interesting to look at there.

I was about to dismiss it on the ground that the worst thing one
could do would be to redefine a command called `LC_something`
which could not really be a problem as those are not existing
command names, but then I started to wonder how `bash`
*imported* those environment variables.

What if the variables were called `LC_foo;echo test; f()` for instance? So I decided to have a closer look.

A:

```
$ env -i bash -c 'zzz() { :;}; export -f zzz; env'
[...]
zzz=() {  :
}
```

revealed that my recollection was wrong in that the variables
were not called `myfunction()` but `myfunction` (and it's the
*value* that starts with `()`).

And a quick test:

```
$ env 'true;echo test; f=() { :;}' bash -c :
test
bash: error importing function definition for `true;echo test; f'
```

confirmed my suspicion that the variable name was not sanitized,
and the code was evaluated *upon startup*.

Worse, a lot worse, the *value* was not sanitized either:

```
$ env 'foo=() { :;}; echo test' bash -c :
test
```

That meant that *any* environment variable could be a vector.

That's when I realised the extent of the problem, confirmed that it was
exploitable over HTTP as well (`HTTP_xxx`/`QUERYSTRING`... env vars), other ones like mail processing services, later DHCP (and probably a long list) and
reported it (carefully).

Comment: Interesting reading! Although the comments on the questions make it clear that this might be a bit off-topic for this site, I think that a small amount of Q/A:s like this (with answers written as well and cleanly as this) really is an asset for the site!