# where to place universal bootstrapping code

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian

All my scripts depend on some env vars & shell functions that effectively form a library.

Is there a system-wide place where such bootstrapping code could be placed so it's included in *every* shell session, regardless if it's running in a non-interactive script or user-facing shell?
Eg I'd like to have following function definition to be globally available to be invoked on-demand:

```
function bootstrap() {
    source "some-library.sh"
}
```

Minimally this should work for scripts ran by one specific user, but would prefer a solution that also extends to scripts executed by `root`.

So far I've tried `/etc/profile` & `/etc/bash.bashr` but no joy.

both /etc/{profile,bash.bashrc} had something similar:

```
_inittest_first() {
    echo this is imported from /etc/profile;
}
export -f _inittest_first
```

I presume export is not working due to dash being involved somewhere inbetween, as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/609758/47501)

Comment: For your user or _all_ users of the machine? And on what operating system?

Comment: Mainly for one user, but ideally scripts executed by `root` would also be able to invoke it.
OS is debian.

Comment: Please show us what you added to `/etc/profile` and tell us how you tested it. Did you export the function?