# Shell command audit for a single user

Tags: linux, shell, logs, command, audit

What is the easiest way to log all the commands ran in the all different shells (bash, zsh...) by a certain user to a file, syslog or somewhere else?

Comment: Well bash uses .bash_history in each users home folder to store commands executed for a start.

Comment: This thread may have something helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206159/how-to-track-log-commands-executed-on-a-shell