# Can we find in history command the dates & timing of the command execution

Tags: shell, command-history, timestamps

This command does not give time & date when command was executed. Is this possible to check date & time  with history command or other command.

```
$ history
    1  cd /strswork/strsapp/applications
    2  ll
    3  cd UM1
    4  ll
    5  cd DEV/oldlogs
    6  ls -ltr
    7  cd ..
    8  ls -ltr
    9  tail -10 log.txt
   10  more log.txt
```

Comment: What shell are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The history command reads from the `~/.bash_history` file which only stores the commands, one on each line. It does not store any timing information.

There are tools that can log both commands and times e.g. auditd ([How to track/log commands executed on a shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206159/how-to-track-log-commands-executed-on-a-shell))

Answer (score 0):

edit .`bash_profile` or `/etc/profile`
add `HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "` end of the line. and refresh it with the below command:

```
source /etc/profile
```