# What do the commas in "${var,,}" mean?

Tags: bash

```
read -p "Enter yes/no   " SOMEVAR

SOMEVAR=`"echo ${SOMEVAR,,}"`
```

The code above gives me a `${SOMEVAR,,}: bad substitution` error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The parameter expansion `${variable,,}` would expand to the value of `$variable` with all character in lower case in the `bash` shell.  Given that you get a "bad substitution" error when this code runs suggests that you are in fact either

- not using that shell but possibly `/bin/sh` (which is not always `bash`). But not getting an error for `read -p` suggests that it's more likely that you are
- using an older release of `bash` which does not support this expansion (introduced in release 4 of `bash`).

The generic form of the expansion is `${variable,,pattern}` in which all characters in `$variable` that matches `pattern` would be converted to lower case (use `^^` to convert to upper case):

```
$ str="HELLO"
$ printf '%s\n' "${str,,[HEO]}"
heLLo
```

See also the `bash` manual on your system.

---

For older releases of `bash`, you could instead do the following to lowercase the value of a variable:

```
variable=$( tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' <<<"$variable" )
```

This passes the value of the variable through `tr` using a "here-string". The `tr` utility transliterates all characters in the `A` to `Z` ASCII range (assuming the C/POSIX locale) to the corresponding character in the `a` to `z` range.

---

Note also that

```
SOMEVAR=`"echo ${SOMEVAR,,}"`
```

is better written as

```
SOMEVAR=${SOMEVAR,,}
```

In fact, what you wrote would give you a "command not found" error in `bash` release 4+, unless you have a command called `echo string`, including the space (where `string` was what the user inputted).  This is due to the command substitution trying to execute the double quoted string.

Comment: or they have a pre-4.0 Bash (like the 3.2 on Macs)

Comment: @ilkkachu Well spotted!

Comment: @Kusalananda thank you for the explanation and the HELLO example. Though this is part of an installation script which has #!/bin/bash at the start.

Comment: @HitanshuSachania The script _assumes_ that you have a more recent `bash` installed in `/bin/bash`.  To fix that, try installing a newer `bash` using Homebrew (if you're on macOS) and then run the script with that `bash` as `/usr/local/bin/bash installscript` (or whatever the script is called), or change the `#!`-line to point to the newer `bash`.

Comment: @HitanshuSachania If it's macOS, then I would _not_ recommend replacing the `/bin/bash` binary with a newer version.

Comment: @Kusalananda it's Ubuntu on my university's cluster. The BASH version is 3.2.51. I've asked them to update it which might take a while, but are you certain updating BASH might resolve this error?

Comment: @HitanshuSachania If `bash` is updated past release 4 (the latest is release 5.0), it is guaranteed to work.  Well, the `${variable,,}` thing will work anyway.  Also note that an Ubuntu installation running a `bash` that is _that_ old is uncommon (it must be older than Ubuntu 14, which has reached its end of life now), and I would seriously question the sysadmin's dedication to keeping the system up to date and secure.

Comment: @HitanshuSachania if they really have a bash version 3.2, then they're probably using Ubuntu 8.04 since [that was the last one](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/ubuntu-8.04-dvd-amd64.list) to ship with a 3.2 bash. That's almost 11 years old! Using software that old is an enormous security risk. In fact, there is [a whopping huge bug](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/157381/22222) in bash itself. That should be a good way of convincing them to upgrade although any sysadmin who has allowed this to happen is a bigger security risk than the bugs themselves.

Comment: @Kusalananda sorry, that was an error from my side. The system has SUSE Linux (Release: 11).

Comment: @terdon the system actually has SUSE Linux (Release: 11). Don't know how I believed it had Ubuntu.

Comment: @HitanshuSachania Still, that's from 2009 (end of support in 2010) and the `bash` installed on it would likely be a security risk in itself.

Comment: @Kusalananda I shall take this point to them. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @Kusalananda I have BASH 5 in the system now but the error persists.

`while [[ $SOMEVAR = "" ]] ; do

        read -n 3 -p "Do you agree with license terms and conditions? (y/n)  " SOMEVAR

        SOMEVAR=`echo "${SOMEVAR,,}"`
    done


    if [[ "$SOMEVAR" == "y" || "$SOMEVAR" == "yes" ]]  ; then`

This is how the erroneous part of the script is.

Comment: @HitanshuSachania The `echo` should not be there. See the second part of my answer. Do you still get a "bad substitution" error?

Comment: @Kusalananda Sorry for the late reply. Changing the script according to the 2nd part of your answer worked. Thank you. Though I still don't understand why did the original script not work for me but worked for others.