# Some bash functions run but can't be exported (no `export` failure either)

Tags: bash, environment-variables, function

I tested this:

```
~$ test() { echo foo |sed -r s/.*(.)/\\1/g; }
~$ test
o
```

So far so good. But then:

```
~$ export -f test
~$ bash -c ''
bash: test: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: test: line 0: `test () {  echo foo | sed -r s/.*(.)/\\1/g'
bash: error importing function definition for `test'
```

I know using quotes with `sed` solves the problem. But bash not exporting a function that runs is alarming and requires explanations, rules and cases.

I would expect bash to be able to handle its own quoting, so I think it can only be a bug.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does env x='() { :;}; command' bash do and why is it insecure?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157329/what-does-env-x-command-bash-do-and-why-is-it-insecure)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I don't see any relation to the linked question other than the fact that this question is using an exported function, which is a fully supported bash feature.

Comment: @Inian I did the testing suggested there. My system fully passed the test; it's patched. I guess you can (vote to) remove the "This question may already have an answer here" box now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have 2 versions of `bash` on your system, and that when you're calling `bash -c ''`, you're invoking a different version. That or your code was altered when you created the question.

As for why I think this, your code does not work on my system:

```
$ test() { echo foo |sed -r s/.*(.)/\\1/g; }
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

The issue is that you have no quotes around the `sed` expression, so bash is trying to interpret it as a shell expression. I'm guessing this behavior changed between bash versions, and that your login shell is a different version of `bash` than whatever is in your `$PATH` when calling `bash -c ''`.
You can check this by doing:

```
$ echo $SHELL
$ which bash
```

Another possible cause would be if you have some shell options set which are changing the behavior of bash's expression evaluation, and these options are not being used by the `bash -c ''`.

As for how to fix the issue, when I properly quote the `sed` expression, it works fine:

```
$ test() { echo foo | sed 's/.*\(.\)/\1/g'; }
$ export -f test
$ bash -c 'test'
o
```

*(Note: I had to slighly tweak the `sed` command as it's not a valid command for my version of `sed`)*

Comment: Not versions, but indeed `--norc` makes the difference.

Comment: Please run `. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion || . /etc/bash_completion` first and tell me if you get the same behavior. This is the culprit, in my `.bashrc`. I am also curious if you have an explanation.